# How to modify Google Maps URL to display a set of marked locations?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps, web

Is there a way to modify just a URL to display a set of locations with markers on them?

I have all the latitude and longitude coordinates of the places I want to mark. How do I construct the URL?

```
https://www.google.ca/maps/@43.200000,-72.000000,15z
```

Do I just add more @ signs and add more sets of coords? How do you put markers on them?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this: [link](https://www.google.com/maps/place/36%C2%B015'56.8%22N+92%C2%B032'35.7%22W/@36.274915,-92.5641396,13z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x0:0x0) . Just change coordinates.
Note: this refering to the same place: 36°15'56.8"N+92°32'35.7"W/@36.2755246,-92.5637963